# Can't figure out errors during c++ python binding using Boost

Tags: python, c++, qt, boost

I am creating a Qt based app that requires python code to be run from it. For this, I am using Boost.Python. The error I have is:

```
CMakeFiles/App.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main.cpp':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3): undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [source/App] Error 1
make[1]: *** [source/CMakeFiles/App.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
11:12:47: The process "/usr/local/bin/cmake" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project App (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

I am sure the error is linking error, but I cant figure out how to remove it. I have just started using cmake and am not proficient at it. 
The code is here : 
`https://github.com/daemonSlayer/App`

What should I change in the code to make it work?

Edit: 

[/root] CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

# Default configuration values. These must be before the project command or
# they won't work in Windows.
# If no build type is specified, default to "Release"
if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING
      "None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel"
      FORCE)
endif()
# Install to "dist" directory in Windows for testing and as a staging directory
# for the installer.
if (WIN32 AND NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX dist CACHE STRING "Install path prefix.")
endif()

project(App)
set(PROJECT_LONGNAME "DeepLearningApp")
set(PROJECT_VERSION "0.0.1")

# Global CMake options
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Configure Qt
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Test REQUIRED)

# Configure Boost
find_package(python)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

if (NOT MSVC)
  # Enable the C++11 standard
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11)
endif()

# Testing configuration
enable_testing()
set(TEST_LINK_LIBRARIES Qt5::Test)

add_subdirectory(source)
add_subdirectory(tests)

if (WIN32)
```

[/root/source] CMakeLists.txt:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/defines.h.cmake
               ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/defines.h)

file(GLOB_RECURSE UI_FILES *.ui)
file(GLOB_RECURSE CODE_FILES *.cpp)

qt5_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS ${UI_FILES})
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCE_FILES ../resources/resources.qrc)

# Windows application icon
if (WIN32)
  set(WINDOWS_RES_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/resources.obj)
  if (MSVC)
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${WINDOWS_RES_FILE}
      COMMAND rc.exe /fo ${WINDOWS_RES_FILE} resources.rc
      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/win
    )
  else()
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${WINDOWS_RES_FILE}
      COMMAND windres.exe resources.rc ${WINDOWS_RES_FILE}
      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/win
    )
  endif()
endif()

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} WIN32
  ${UI_HEADERS}
  ${CODE_FILES}
  ${RESOURCE_FILES}
  ${WINDOWS_RES_FILE}
)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
  Qt5::Widgets
)

# Configure Python
find_package( PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# Configure Boost
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

if (UNIX)
  install(TARGETS ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
          RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
elseif (WIN32)
  install(TARGETS ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
          DESTINATION .)
endif()


  add_subdirectory(win)
endif()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to create a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the code in your question. Don't link to external sites for crucial parts of your post as these services might go out of business.

Comment: Please show us the CMakeLists.txt, it would be much easier to figure out the problem then.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the cmake files. Please explain the changes required.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are not linking with the required Python libraries. Try adding `${PYTHON_LIBRARIES$} to`target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} 
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
)
```